# Algorithmic improvement for finding minimum sum in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, binary-search-tree

I wrote the following function to find out the minimum sum of any path in a Binary Search Tree:

```
int minSumPath(TreeNode* root) {
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;

    int sum = root->value;
    if(root->left!=NULL && root->right!=NULL)
        sum += min(minSumPath(root->left),minSumPath(root->right));
    else
        if(root->left==NULL)
            sum += minSumPath(root->right);
        else
            sum += minSumPath(root->left);

    return sum;
}
```

While the above code generates the correct output, I feel that I am not leveraging the fact that it is a Binary Search Tree (BST) and not just a Binary Tree.

In a BST the left child node is smaller than the root and right node, so logically we can only consider the left child nodes of each root; but what if the BST has only a single child on the right (with say value 10) and multiple child nodes on the left (with sum >10)?

In this case the minimum sum would be 10 (which is on the right).

How I would be able to leverage the BST property, if at all? Also, any other optimizations that I can use in my approach?

Note: Edited the code to resolve the error;

Comment: Recursion is great and all, but an iterative approach is often better because it doesn't rely on utilizing the stack for function calls, which can be costly in a large tree.

Comment: @user3112926, while I totally agree with you sir, I am seeking algorithmic improvements.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by minimum sum of any path? The sum of all node values along a path from the root node to any leaf?

Comment: You're exactly right. The fact that the tree is a BST doesn't help.  If it were a _balanced_ tree, you could use the balance condition to limit the search, but it would be more complicated than just descending the left child. You'd have to search the left subtree and then omit the right if the balance condition plus minimum node value made it impossible for a right subtree search to produce a smaller sum.

Comment: @Nobody, yes you are right.

Comment: @A.S.H, could you please elaborate what error you see in the code?

Comment: I dont know why I cant see the function returning anything else but zero.

Comment: As a nice code improvement: Since you already check `root` for `NULL` you can omit the null checks on the other levels and simply call `minSumPath` with the `NULL`s that are in `left` or `right`.

Comment: @Nobody, sorry, could you please elaborate?  I checked the `root` to be `NULL` in the beginning; later on I check `root->left` and `root->right`.

Comment: Yes, but in the next recursion step `root->left` and `root->right` will be the new `root` which is again checked for `NULL`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I got you!  Thank you, @Nobody. :)

Comment: Hopefully, the cleaned up code should make the error @A.S.H is talking about more visible.

Comment: The question is interesting though. There must be some way to exploit the BST's structure.

Comment: We can accelerate the traversal by computing first, at each node, the left sub-tree and comparing the sum with the right child's value. If that value is already more than the computed sum of the left sub-tree, no need to traverse the right sub-tree. That's an improvement, but it is still possible to do better.

Comment: @A.S.H, yes it will help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An informed search could help in some cases.
In the worst case, the computational cost is exactly the same of your algorithm.

As an example:

```
int minSumPathOpt(TreeNode* root) {
    if(root == nullptr) return 0;

    int sum = -1;

    std::stack<std::pair<TreeNode*, int>> todo;
    todo.push(std::make_pair(root, 0));

    while(not todo.empty()) {
        std::pair<TreeNode*, int> curr = todo.top();
        todo.pop();

        TreeNode *node = curr.first;        
        int part = curr.second + node->value;

        if(sum == -1 || part < sum) {
            if(!node->left && !node->right) {
                sum = part;
            } else  {
                if(node->right) todo.push(std::make_pair(node->right, part));
                if(node->left) todo.push(std::make_pair(node->left, part));
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The basic idea is to track the current minimum while performing a DFS. This will give you the chance to prune entire subtrees whenever the sum of the values to their root are already greater than the current minimum.
Moreover, exploring the left tree before to look at the right one could help maximizing the result (no assurance indeed, but it's a good idea because of how BSTs are defined).

See a comparison of the two approaches on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ecnBSzdD9BvDwlmL).
As you can see, the second function doesn't explore at all trees that are not promising.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you see some way in which we can exploit the BST property?

Comment: @user6490375 I suspect pruning not promising subtrees is the best you can do. BSTs don't necessarily minimize the result on a specific subtree. You can easily construct a tree that has the shortest path on the left subtree and one that has the shortest path on the right subtree. Those will probably defeat any attempt to exploit the fact that lower values are to the left or something like that.